# Format plot axis of multiindex dataframe one for title one for date without time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to line plot this multiindexed pandas dataframe with the Ticker as the title (ie IVOG) and the date as the x-axis.  I only want the month and year for the x-axis. I want to at least get rid of it showing the time.

```
df[['Adj_Close', 'MA(3)', 'EWMA(3)']]
                   Adj_Close      MA(3)    EWMA(3)
Ticker Date                                       
IVOG   2017-04-30    47.0319  47.031900  47.031900
       2017-05-31    47.4419  47.236900  47.305233
       2017-06-30    46.3553  46.943033  46.762414
       2017-07-31    49.6553  47.817500  48.305287
       2017-08-31    52.5453  49.518633  50.493681
       2017-09-30    55.5353  52.578633  53.054503
       2017-10-31    57.3753  55.151967  55.231913
       2017-11-30    55.5353  56.148633  55.384201
       2017-12-31    59.6556  57.522067  57.524080
       2018-01-31    61.7056  58.965500  59.616884
       2018-02-28    58.8156  60.058933  59.216046
       2018-03-31    58.9600  59.827067  59.087992
       2018-04-30    58.9000  58.891867  58.993984
       2018-05-31    59.0000  58.953333  58.996992
```

I have tried many things  The following code is the closest I have gotten.  I converted the dataframe to a dict so I could present it here. I lost the index headers and the date format in doing so. But it should be something reproducible now.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {("IVOG",1493510400000):{"Adj_Close":119.2136,"MA(3)":119.2136,"EWMA(3)":119.2136},
        ("IVOG",1496188800000):{"Adj_Close":120.8236,"MA(3)":120.0186,"EWMA(3)":120.0454},
        ("IVOG",1498780800000):{"Adj_Close":120.2736,"MA(3)":120.1036,"EWMA(3)":120.1266},
        ("IVOG",1501459200000):{"Adj_Close":121.7836,"MA(3)":120.5236,"EWMA(3)":120.5832},
        ("IVOG",1504137600000):{"Adj_Close":120.3536,"MA(3)":120.4896,"EWMA(3)":120.5309},
        ("IVOG",1506729600000):{"Adj_Close":124.3336,"MA(3)":121.1303,"EWMA(3)":121.2749}}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index')
print(df)
ax = plt.gca()      # get current axis
df.plot(kind='line',y='Adj_Close', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='MA(3)',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',y='EWMA(3)', color='green', ax=ax)
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y')     # Trying to get APR-2018
plt.xlabel(df.index[0])     # Trying to Get the Ticker
_=plt.grid()
_=plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Instead it plots like this:
[Plot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cT0I.png)

Comment: xlabel is the title of the axis x in the plot; thus this sounds wrong: `plt.xlabel(df.index[0])     # Trying to Get the Ticker`;

xticks is whatever is written for each tick in the x-axis in the plot. Which one do you want to change? Both?

I can't reproduce the example with the data shown like that (if you posted something that people could copy-paste and run that would be much easier!)

Check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This may help? `string = '2017-10-3'` `another = string.split('-')`
`another[1]` gives output as `'10'`

Comment: nahusznaj, I would like just "IVOG" across the bottom with the ticks labeled with the dates.  I edited the code so it could be reproduced as you asked but somehow lost the date format and the index titles.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert but I can't even understand very well what the question is. The format of the question is too complicated: why is there two different datasets? Maybe you could try to clarify what's the question, show an example of what you tried, and describe precisely what you want. I would personally delete this question and post it again with a clearer structure/presentation? 

If you change this line you'll get the label that I think you wanted: `plt.xlabel(df.index[0][0]) `